# How to convert two columns of dataframe into named vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, lapply, reshape2

I'm trying to convert a dataframe consisting of two columns into a named vector (nested list). The information in each row is essentially key:value pairs, so the lists in the final vector should each be named by the keys and contain their respective values.

```
Example input:

Var1   Var2
A      1
A      2
B      1
B      3
C      3
C      4
C      5

Example Output:
namedArray = list(A = c(1,2), B = c(1,3), C = c(3,4,5))
```

I managed to do this using `dcast()` in the reshape2 package, however this required additional post-processing to remove row names and NA's introduced by casting the data frame.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 2 columns: X and Y in dataframe df1, and you want Y's values to be the names of items with values from X:

```
myList <- as.list(df1$X)
names(myList) <- df1$Y
```

For the modified question, the answer is that there is already a functions that does exactly that ( and might have been a better answer that what I gave:

```
> split(dat$Var2, dat$Var1)
$A
[1] 1 2

$B
[1] 1 3

$C
[1] 3 4 5
```

Comment: I was unclear by omitting an example in my original question. I need a solution that handles one-many relationships between the two variables.

Comment: That makes it even more clear that `split` is a completely satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @42- and @MMerry for getting me to think about split(). I found a nice solution splitting one variable by the other and wrapping the output into a list.

```
y <- as.list(split(df$Var2, df$Var1))
```

Comment: Hi @flowscience, `split()` should output a list so you can skip wrapping it in the `as.list()` call. Can you also marked this as answered as it helps other users

Answer (score 0):

If you want key value pairs in a list from a data frame a technique could look like this:

```
x = data.frame(x=letters[1:5],y=1:5)
y = split(x,seq(1:nrow(x)))
names(y) = x$x
y$a
```

Comment: This gives the same result as the answer given above by @42-